# Imageview descargar imagen con Glide o Picasso

Tags: java, android

> ¿Se utilizar Glide o Picasso con recursos locales ?

Tengo un imageview en un recycler que además es un elemento compartido con un activity detalle.

> ¿Cómo cargo esa imagen en el imageview con Glide o Picasso ?

Comment: Ya lo edite, gracias por avisar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Cargar imagen con Glide o Picasso.

---

**Glide**
Con glide  se realiza de forma similar:

```
   Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.android).into(imageView);
```

agregando la dependencia dentro de tu archivo build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    ...
}
```

**Picasso :**
Con Picasso puedes cargar imagenes definidas en los recursos por ejemplo una imagen llamada `android.jpg` dentro de `/drawable`:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.android).into(imageView);
```

agregando la respectiva dependencia dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828
    ...
}
```

con ambas opciones tendrías el mismo resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

#### Imagen desde una URL

Puedes también descargar una imagen proveniente de una url, en este caso en lugar de la referencia a el directorio `/drawable` se define una url:

Glide:

```
  Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```

Picasso:

```
Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```