# Android ¿Cuál es la mejor forma para descargar y tratar una imagen de internet?

Tags: java, android

Muy buenas, estoy haciendo una aplicación que crea un número alto de botones con un fondo de imagen que cogen de mi servidor web. El problema viene cuando llego a un alto número de fotos o el peso es demasiado elevado, ya que la aplicación se detiene.

Las descargo de la siguiente manera en una llamada asíncrona:

```
                   Bitmap myIcon= null;
                    try {
                        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(logoURL).openStream();
                        myIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    logos[i] = myIcon;
```

Y en la post ejecución, los pongo como fondo del botón en el postExecute:

```
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), (logos[i]));
        btnCanales[i].setBackground(d);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por suerte para nosotros existen las librerías de terceros que nos ahorran tiempo y que hará las cosas mucho mas óptimas que nosotros.. Te presento a Picasso, desarrollada por square y que permite en un par de líneas gestionar la descarga asíncrona de una imagen y su posterior carga en pantalla:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:(insert latest version)'
```

Mas info [aquí](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Answer (score 2):

En Google Developers recomiendan usar la librería Glide. Picasso también es una buena opción como recomiendoa @Corpex.
Pero sino tenés la opción de usar BitmapFactory.Options para redimensionar o escalar la imagen para que no ocupe tanta memoria.

Te dejo el link a Google Developers.

[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 2):

> El problema viene cuando llego a un alto número de fotos o el peso es
>   demasiado elevado, ya que la aplicación se detiene.

Una solución rápida es eliminar la imagen del ImageView cuando esta no es visualizada mediante [setBackgroundDrawable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) asignandole un valor null:

```
miImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

Pero existen otras consideraciones importantes como es el peso de la imagen, en dispositivos pequeños en ocasiones no es necesario el cargado de una imagen de tamaño grande ya que su manipulación en memoria es difícil y más aún si tenemos varias instancias provocaremos  `OutofMemory`.

Te sugiero revisar estos tips de optimización:
**[Buena resolución imagen](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6359/95)**

y en el caso recomiendo uses **[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)** o **[Glide](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)** para cargar las imágenes dentro del `ImageView`, son 2 buenas opciones que recomiendo, en realidad optimizan la imagen que cargan dentro de los `ImageView`, esto resulta en un bajo consumo de memoria el cual evitara problemas relacionados a `OutofMemory`.

**[Imageview con Glide o Picasso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73030/imageview-con-glide-o-picasso)**