# Mostrar imagen traida de una base de datos en Android Studio

Tags: php, android, sql

Queremos mostrar una imagen, guardada previamente en una base de datos y que se muestre en el layout de android pero no sabemos como hacerlo. De momento tenemos esto:

```
AccesoPHP aPHP = new AccesoPHP();

        is = aPHP.ejecutar("http://"+IP+"/imagen.php");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(is);

        String ima = null;


        URL imageUrl = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.img);


        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, sc.next(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                Toast.makeText(this, ima, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                imageUrl = new URL(ima);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
                conn.connect();

                Bitmap imagen = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
                img.setImageBitmap(imagen);


            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            sc.close();

        }
```

Comment: Que se obtiene si consulto : http://"+IP+"/imagen.php ?

Comment: la url de la foto y un nombre con la que se guarda. Asi mismo +IP+ es una variable que tenemos creada con la IP que tenemos en ese momento

Comment: ¿entonces is es un string conteniendo la ruta de la imagen?

Comment: Si, y supongo que a partir de eso se mostraria la imagen pero no sabemos como hacerlo

Comment: Se debe obtener el bitmap del recurso y este asignarlo a el ImageView, no es necesario usar Scanner() , agregué una respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

ok si obtienes la url de la imagen :

```
String is = aPHP.ejecutar("http://"+IP+"/imagen.php");
```

puedes usar varios métodos, por ejemplo un `Asynctask`:

```
   class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        public LoadImage(ImageView imageView) {
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("LoadImage class", "doInBackground() " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                bitmap = null;
            }

            if (imageViewReference != null) {
                ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                URL uri = new URL(url);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    return null;
                }

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    return bitmap;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
                Log.e("LoadImage class", "Descargando imagen desde url: " + url);
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

que usarías de esta forma, obteniendo la instancia del `ImageView` en donde agregarás la imagen y enviar la url de la imagen para que se obtenga el bitmap y se agregue a el `ImageView`.

```
String is = aPHP.ejecutar("http://"+IP+"/imagen.php");

ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.img);
 new LoadImage(img).execute(is);
```

Otras opciones son el uso de [**Glide o Picasso**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73030/imageview-con-glide-o-picasso).

Comment: +1 Por mencionar el uso del AsyncTask y la opción de Picasso