# ¿java.lang.OutOfMemoryError... en recycler-view?

Tags: java, android-studio, recyclerview, out-of-memory-error

ERROR:

> 2019-07-25 23:35:33.030 13258-13258/com.example.imagenes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.imagenes, PID: 13258
>       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1179136012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 350MB until OOM
>           at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:858)
>           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
>           at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:162)
>           at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:150)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:71)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:67)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:181)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:105)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)

Fuera de memoria, he intentado poner mil soluciones como en `Manifest` el `android:largeHeap="true"` típico y otro que se suele comentar pero nada, si pongo iconos en vez de imágenes grandes sí que va, por lo que es el tamaño, ¿cómo puedo incorporar imágenes de 10 MB o más en mi App o tiene un límite y tengo que bajarlas a 5MB o cuánto?

**Landscape.java:**

`public class Landscapes extends AppCompatActivity {`

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
int[] mPlaceList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_landscapes);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    GridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(Landscapes.this, 2);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);

    mPlaceList = new int[]{R.drawable.calendar, R.drawable.coliseum, R.drawable.park,
            R.drawable.salad};

    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(Landscapes.this, mPlaceList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

}

**activity_landscape.xml:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

**Adapter.java:**

`public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlaceViewHolder> {`

```
private Context mContext;
private int[] mPlaceList;

public MyAdapter(Context mContext, int[] mPlaceList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mPlaceList = mPlaceList;
}

@Override
public PlaceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_custom_layout,
            parent, false);
    return new PlaceViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PlaceViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mPlace.setImageResource(mPlaceList[position]);
    holder.mPlace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("Image", mPlaceList[holder.getAdapterPosition()]);
            mContext.startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPlaceList.length;
}
```

}

`class PlaceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {`

```
ImageView mPlace;

public PlaceViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    mPlace = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivPlace);
}
```

}

**activity_Detail.xml**:

unicamente tengo el imageView con id: imageView

**Detail.activity.java**:

`public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {`

```
ImageView mPlace;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    mPlace = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(mBundle != null){
        mPlace.setImageResource(mBundle.getInt("Image"));
    }
}
```

}

Actualizo error:

> 2019-07-26 18:07:59.533 16235-16235/com.example.imagenes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.imagenes, PID: 16235
>       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1179136012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 343MB until OOM
>           at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
>           at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
>           at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:358)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
>           at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:93)
>           at com.example.imagenes.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.java:19)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: Hay algún motivo especifico por el cual las imagenes tengan que ir en su resolución original dentro del recycler view? Si no lo hay, te recomiendo manejar miniaturas dentro del recicyler view utilizando Picasso o Glide y agregar una funcion de Zoom una vez seleccionado el elemento, esto para evitar la carga de la memoria RAM del dispositivo ya que el Garbage collector no puede limpiarla tan rapido como paparecen dentro de tu recycler view.

Comment: Hola Rafa, considera usar Glide o Picasso, trata de implementarlo, si tienes problemas agrega el Adapter y te puedo ayudar a indicar como realizarlo, saludos.

Comment: Perfecto, es lo que quiero si, agregaré un Glide o Picasso para que sean miniaturas y que al pinchar salga la imagen original. Veré que tal mañana y os comento, gracias

Comment: He editado la respuesta con el adapter porque se me crashea la App , a ver si consigues ayudarme por favor @Jorgesys

Comment: @RfMvs definitivamente el mismo error pero ahora en la Activity, en la Activity también puedes usar Glide para cargar la imagen en el ImageView, revisa mi respuesta, Pero no olvides optimizar tus imágenes, considero que no necesitan medir 10MB si se van a desplegar en un dispositivo móvil.

Comment: Vale, de acuerdo, pues sí que va, muchas gracias, ahora mismo te doy como respuesta válida, no sabia que se pudiera hacer en ambos lugares. Pero antes una cosa, al clickar en la imagen y salirme, funciona como he dicho, pero me sale como ampliada... y no sale toda la foto, si no solo una parte, eso como se soluciona? crees que si pongo fotos de 10 MB maximo se solucionaria? o hay alguna funcion dentro de Glide que me las centre y se vea toda la imagen tal como se ve en la miniatura?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola Rafa es un problema se indica aquí:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1179136012 byte
>   allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 350MB

Tus imágenes del directorio `/Drawable` que son :

```
R.drawable.calendar, R.drawable.coliseum, R.drawable.park,
            R.drawable.salad
```

Tienen un  tamaño considerable y no pueden ser alojadas en memoria, considera optimizarlas.

Puedes revisar la información de esta pregunta:

[Buena resolución de imagen causa "OutOfMemoryError"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/buena-resoluci%c3%b3n-de-imagen-causa-outofmemoryerror)

como opción puedes usar `GLIDE` o `Picasso`, aquí puedes encontrar ejemplos:

[Imageview descargar imagen con Glide o Picasso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73030/imageview-descargar-imagen-con-glide-o-picasso)

---

**Glide** Con `Glide`, puedes cargar imágenes definidas en los recursos por ejemplo una imagen llamada `android.jpg` dentro de `/drawable`:

```
   Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.android).into(imageView);
```

agregando la dependencia dentro de tu archivo build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    ...
}
```

**Picasso :**
Con `Picasso` puedes cargar imagenes definidas en los recursos por ejemplo una imagen llamada `android.jpg` dentro de `/drawable`:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.android).into(imageView);
```

agregando la respectiva dependencia dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
   implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828
    ...
}
```

con ambas opciones tendrías el mismo resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Actualización:**

Para implementar `Glide`, debes realizarlo en tu Adapter.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PlaceViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //holder.mPlace.setImageResource(mPlaceList[position]);
    //Carga imagen en ImageView usando Glide.
    Glide.with(context).load(mPlaceList[position]).into(holder.mPlace);

    holder.mPlace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("Image", mPlaceList[holder.getAdapterPosition()]);
            mContext.startActivity(mIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

También puedes usar `Glide` al cargar la imagen en la Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    mPlace = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(mBundle != null){
        //mPlace.setImageResource(mBundle.getInt("Image"));
        //Carga imagen en ImageView usando Glide.
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mBundle.getInt("Image")).into(mPlace);
    }
}
```

Comment: Debo  introducir ``Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.android).into(imageView);`` donde antes ponía ``R.drawable.coliseum...`` no? El problema es que desde ``Landscapes.java`` cargo ``activity_landscapes.xml`` el cual no tiene ``imageView``, si no un ``recyclerview`` , eso puede dar problemas no?

Comment: @RfMvs es en el adapter, he actualizado la respuesta de acuerdo al código de tu Adapter, saludos.

Comment: ahora funciona, pero yo antes pinchaba en una de esas imagenes y se ampliaba y ahora clicko y me da un error y se me crashea la App...

Comment: Siempre acostumbra agregar el error que se muestra en el LogCat, donde dice "Caused by".... @RfMvs

Comment: Lo he actualizado arriba ya, parece ser lo mismo, fuera de memoria, pero no entiendo, la imagen pensaba que sí que podia verla ampliada individualmente... entonces...? Las imagenes que he subido a la App van desde los 300 KB hasta los 17 MB por eso he usado el ``Glide`` pero se ve que se crashea tambien cuando las intento seleccionar...

Comment: He introducido el ``DetailActivity.java`` en la edición también por si ayuda..