# Android tamaño de la aplicacion con muchas imagenes HD

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para `Android` en `visual studio`. Actualmente mi aplicación tiene una `Activity` principal con 1 fondo de pantalla y otra `Activity` con una `listView` de 200 elementos con una imagen en cada uno de 100x100. Esa aplicación en el celular ya pesa **25 MB**.

He visto aplicaciones en `playstore` que tienen muchas mas imágenes y todas vienen en HD y aun asi la aplicación no pesa mas de **10 MB**.

También haciendo algunas pruebas me di cuenta que esas aplicaciones van aumentando de su tamaño a medida que voy visualizando mas imágenes.

Mi pregunta es como se puede hacer esto? Que la aplicación al principio pese poco y vaya ocupando mas espacio a medida que el usuario visualice cada vez mas y mas elementos.

PD: Aclaro que esas aplicaciones de `playstore` eran bastante simples y dudo mucho que el desarrollador haya creado un servicio web o un servidor que mande imágenes por peticiones.

Comment: supongo que tomas las imagenes en su formato original y las pones directamente a la aplicacion
Intenta subirlas a Firebase storage y las tomas de ahi, o conviertelas a formato SVG y las cargas en la app eso deberia disminuir el peso de la aplicacion y de la imagen

Answer (score 1):

> He visto aplicaciones en playstore que tienen muchas mas imágenes y
>   todas vienen en HD y aun así la aplicación no pesa mas de 10 MB.

Si al descargar y usar la aplicación, esta despliega imágenes pero no crece en tamaño se debe a dos causas:

- No descarga imágenes y no guarda datos en caché.
- La aplicación tiene  los recursos en la misma aplicación.

> Mi pregunta es como se puede hacer esto? Que la aplicación al
>   principio pese poco y vaya ocupando mas espacio a medida que el
>   usuario visualice cada vez mas y mas elementos.

Esto se debe a que la aplicación cuenta con manejo de caché y realiza descarga de información , obviamente el almacenamiento de esta información tienen un limite y se tiene una depuración automática de la misma para evitar que crezca indefinidamente.

Incluso si haces uso de libraries como [Glide](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73030/imageview-descargar-imagen-con-glide-o-picasso) o [Picasso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73030/imageview-descargar-imagen-con-glide-o-picasso), estas implementan caché para evitar descargar innecesariamente información.

---

El implementar caché en tus aplicaciones tiene algunas ventajas como son:

- Al tener en caché o en disco las imágenes, no necesitas descargarlas nuevamente, para el usuario esto es beneficioso ya que la aplicación no tendrá gran consumo de datos.
- Al tener en caché o en disco las imágenes, el acceso a las imágenes será mucho más rápido ya que no necesita descargarlas nuevamente.

Answer (score -1):

Si las imágenes vienen dentro de tu proyecto, te recomiendo convertirlas a WebP para que pesen menos y el apk pese menos

> 1.-Posiciónate en tu carpeta Drawable.
>   2.-Selecciona las imágenes que quieres convertir a WebP.
>   3.-Da clic derecho sobre ellas.
>   4.-Selecciona "Convert to WebP"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esto debería ayudarte a reducir el peso de la app instalada en tu dispositivo.

Aquí la referencia:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/convert-webp